# Accessing data from a vector of objects

Tags: c++

I have read in data from a file and want to store the data as a vector of objects.

```
vector <Thing*> thingVector;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
// Read in contents of file
getline(fileName, v1, ',');
cout << v1 << endl;
getline(fileName, v1, ',');
cout << v2 << endl;
getline(fileName, v3, ',');
cout << v3 << endl;
getline(fileName, v4, '\n');
cout << v4 << endl << endl;
// Store
Thing* thingDetails = new Thing(v1, v2, v3, v4);
thingVector.push_back(thingDetails);
delete thingDetails;
}
thingFile.close();
cout << "Size of THING vector is " << thingVector.size() << endl; // Displays 10

cout << thingVector[0].getV1 << endl; // ERROR HERE
```

How can I store each record in the vector and then access the data?

I also tried to do it like this:
    thingVector.push_back(Thing(v1, v2, v3, v4));

I didn't have the last and third to last lines in the for statement when I tried it like this, but I couldn't access the data so gave up on this method.

Any suggestions?

THING .H FILE

```
#ifndef THING_H
#define THING_H

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Thing {
public:

Thing(string v1, string v2, string v3, string v4);
string getV1();
string getV2();
string getV3();
string getV4();

private:
string v1;
string v2;
string v3;
string v4;
};

#endif
```

THING .CPP FILE

```
#include "thing.h"

#include <string>

using namespace std;
Thing::Thing(string aV1, string aV2, string aV3, string aV4) {
v1 = aV1;
v2 = aV2;
v3 = aV3;
v4 = aV4;
}

string Thing::getV1(){
return v1;
}

string Thing::getV3(){
return v2;
}

string Thing::getV3){
return v3;
}

string Thing::getV4(){
return v4;
}
```

Comment: You deallocate the object with delete, so you get the error since you are accessing a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
vector <Thing> thingVector;
...
thingVector.push_back(*thingDetails);
```

This will pass object rather than the pointer.

Also

```
cout << thingVector[0].getV1() << endl; // Convert to a function call.
```

Comment: Creating a dynamically allocated object, dereferencing it to put it in the vector, then deleting it seems like an anti-pattern.

Comment: There is no need to dynamically allocate and deallocate the `Thing`, you can just make in automatic storage and put it in the vector.

Comment: I know, but your methodology and my methodology will coincide is not necessary,there are cases where you may still need `Thing(v1,v2,v3,v4)` but your automatic had deleted it.

Comment: Sure, of course. But in this case, there is a call to `new`, a `push_back()`, and a `delete` immediately in succession.

Comment: OK, removed the downvote. But I still think your suggestion constitutes bad advice.

Comment: Thanks, but I will say if you are a learner you should first know,how you can make things work. Because the time will tell you in what way things shouldn't be made to work. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are storing pointers to `Thing`, but are deleting the pointees. So the vector ends up being full of dangling pointers. You can avoid all these troubles by simply using a vector of `Things`:

```
vector <Thing> thingVector;
...
thingVector.push_back(Thing(v1,v2,v3,v4));
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
std::string s = thingVector[0].getV1();
```

or

```
cout << thingVector[0].getV1() << endl;
```

You should not use pointers dynamically allocated objects unless strictly necessary, and in your code sample there seems to be no reason to do so. If you do, consider using [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) to deal with memory management.

Note, if you had opted for a `vector` of `Thing` pointers or smart pointers, then you would have to call each element's methods with the `->` operator:

```
cout << thingVector[0]->getV1() << endl;
                  //   ^ here!
```

BTW you should really avoid `using namespace std;`, specially in header files.

Comment: I did try it like this, but how do I access the object data?  I have tried :  cout << thingVector[0].getV1 << endl;
but I get a huge error which takes up a whole screen!  What is the correct way to reference the variable v1?

Comment: @Sandra I cannot say without seeing the declaration of the `Thing` class. Can you post that?

Comment: @Sandra OK, you were missing the `()`. I added an example.

Comment: @Sandra:- `cout << thingVector[0].getV1() << endl;`

Comment: My goodness!  How silly of me.  Yes. It works now.  Thanks guys :)

Comment: @Sandra you're welcome. But think seriously about the other issues highlighted in this answer and dasblinkenlight'ŝ one. From your code sample, there is absolutely no need to dynamically allocate a `Thing` and then delete it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code:

- You are deleting the pointer to the `Thing` that you push_back, and
- You are not reading `v2` at all (copy/paste bug; you're reading the data into `v1` twice).

While it is OK to have a vector of pointers, it is inconvenient, because you have to do a lot of manual work to manage object's memory. You can use `unique_ptr<Thing>` instead of `Thing*` in your vector, like this:

```
vector <unique_ptr<Thing> > thingVector;
```